# Setup different user permissions on files copied in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, file-permissions

I have this Dockerfile setup:

```
FROM node:14.5-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app


FROM base AS production
ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN chown -R node:node /app
RUN chmod 755 /app
USER node
... other copies
COPY ./scripts/startup-production.sh ./
COPY ./scripts/healthz.sh ./

CMD ["./startup-production.sh"]
```

The problem I'm facing is that I can't execute `./healthz.sh` because it's only executable by the `node` user. When I commented out the two `RUN` and the `USER` commands, I could execute the file just fine. But I want to enforce the executable permissions only to the `node` for security reasons.

I need the `./healthz.sh` to be externally executable by Kubernetes' liveness & rediness probes.

How can I make it so? Folder restructuring or stuff like that are fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, you probably want your code to be owned by `root`, but to be world-readable, and for scripts be world-executable.  The Dockerfile [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) directive will copy in a file with its existing permissions from the host system (hidden in the list of bullet points at the end is a note that a file "is copied individually along with its metadata").  So the easiest way to approach this is to make sure the script has the right permissions on the host system:

```sh
# mode 0755 is readable and executable by everyone but only writable by owner
chmod 0755 healthz.sh
git commit -am 'make healthz script executable'
```

Then you can just `COPY` it in, without any special setup.

```sh
# Do not RUN chown or chmod; just
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./scripts/healthz.sh .

# Then when launching the container, specify
USER node
CMD ["./startup-production.sh"]
```

You should be able to verify this locally by running your container and manually invoking the health-check script

```sh
docker run -d --name app the-image
# possibly with a `docker exec -u` option to specify a different user
docker exec app /app/healthz.sh && echo OK
```

The important thing to check is that the file is world-executable.  You can also double-check this by looking at the built container

```
docker run --rm the-image ls -l /app/healthz.sh
```

That should print out one line, starting with a permission string `-rwxr-xr-x`; the last three `r-x` are the important part.  If you can't get the permissions right another way, you can also fix them up in your image build

```sh
COPY ./scripts/healthz.sh .
# If you can't make the permissions on the original file right:
RUN chmod 0755 *.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify user Dockerfile CMD command like this :  `["sh", "./startup-production.sh"]`

This will interpret the script as `sh`, but it can be dangerous if your script is using bash specific features like `[[]]` with `#!/bin/bash` as its first line.

Moreover I would say use `ENTRYPOINT` here instead of `CMD` if you want this to run whenever container is up